# WPF Binding xml to datagrid combobox?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, combobox, datagrid

In my WPF project, I have a xml file like this:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Communications>
    <ModelNumber>0x01</ModelNumber>
    <ParamName>BaudRate</ParamName>
    <ParamValue>19200</ParamValue>
    <DefaultValue>502</DefaultValue>
    <MaxValue></MaxValue>
    <MinValue></MinValue>
  </Communications>
</NewDataSet>
```

my current binding xml to datagrid the way like this:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgCommunication" ItemsSource="{Binding CommunicationsView}">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="ParamName" Binding="{Binding ParamName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="ParamValue" Binding="{Binding ParamValues, Mode=TwoWay}" />
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="DefaultValue" Binding="{Binding DefaultValue}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="MaxValue" Binding="{Binding MaxValue}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="MinValue" Binding="{Binding MinValue}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The ItemsSource like this:

```
    private ICollectionView _ModulesView;
    public ICollectionView ModulesView
    {
        get
        {
            if (_ModulesView == null)
                RefreshModules();
            return _ModulesView;
        }
        set
        {
            _ModulesView = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void RefreshModules()
    {
        ModulesView = new ListCollectionView(sdb.GetModules())
        {
            Filter = obj =>
            {
                var Module= (Module)obj;
                return SelectedProduct != null && Product.ModelNumber == SelectedProduct.ModelNumber;
            }
        };
    }
```

The above code works fine.
Now I want to change some of my datagrid cell to comboBox. for example, I want to make `ParamValue` chooseable so I may change my xml file like this:

```
<NewDataSet>
<Communications>
    <ModelNumber>0x01</ModelNumber>
    <ParamName>BaudRate</ParamName>
    <ParamValues>
        <ParamValue>9600</ParamValue>
        <ParamValue>19200</ParamValue>
        <ParamValue>115200</ParamValue>
    </ParamValues>
    <DefaultValue>502</DefaultValue>
    <MaxValue></MaxValue>
    <MinValue></MinValue>
</Communications>
```

What should I suppose to do to make this right?Thanks in advance!

Comment: doesn't this work? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It's not using XML file as datasource.